# Converting url encoded strings into plain text with ruby

Tags: ruby, urlencode

I am writing a script to extract search terms from URLs, but I need to humanize them and many of them have special URL encoded characters in them.  I was wondering if there was a gem or some built in function in Ruby to convert these to plain text? Or will I have to write my own functions to clean them up?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: You're going to have to write them, or figure it out on your own, because you didn't give us enough information to help. We need samples of your input and what you want for output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CGI::unescape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html#method-i-unescape) for URL-decoding:

```
require 'cgi'
string = CGI::unescape("1+%2B+2+%3D+3")
#=> "1 + 2 = 3"
```

Comment: Since it's a URI, I'd probably use `URI.decode_www_form_component("1+%2B+2+%3D+3")
 => "1 + 2 = 3"`

Comment: If the URLs have been encoded correctly, yes. Otherwise,  `CGI::unescape` is more robust: `CGI::unescape("10 %") #=> "10 %"` vs. `URI.decode_www_form_component("10 %") #=> ArgumentError: invalid %-encoding`

Comment: Yes, that's the long-standing issue with URI. There's always Addressable::URI, which was proposed as a replacement to URI.